# Was the poster for "The Green Mile" copied from something else?

Tags: posters, the-green-mile

The poster for *The Green Mile* is hauntingly familiar, but ever since the movie came out I haven't been able to explain my déjà vu.

[image]

Tom Hanks looks somewhat like a toy or doll in the picture. Is this an homage to some specific image from the past?

Comment: the google image search turns up a very similar looking one, but it's only another chracter from the same film (http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/2854538/468full-doug-hutchison.jpg)

Comment: I once saw that this kind of things in some video on youtube, which explained (with visual examples), that numerous modern movies that has very similar posters from older and newer(often from other countries)

Answer (score 3):

The poster is by [Drew Struzan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drew_Struzan), an artist who's responsible for many hand-painted and airbrushed posters. Struzan is responsible for quite a few notable hand-painted posters in the modern era of films (Star Wars, Indiana Jones, etc.) The reason for this poster being in sepia tones and having very soft lighting is to signal that part of the story is set in the past, the 1930s. The combination of the sepia and airbrushed texture is likely meant to evoke the look of photographs from that period. And it's also a bit of a throwback; all movie posters used to be hand-painted, by the 90s not so much. I'm unaware of any specific references that these stylistic choices could be making.